# Is there a way to use create-react-app offline

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I would like to know if there's a way to use create-react-app offline rather than have it download files from the internet everytime. Doing this, seems like a huge waste of bandwith, and time, as internet speed is very slow and expensive where i reside.

Comment: @Jayce444 I believe the dependencies would still need to be downloaded each time

Comment: Well one way or the other, cloning or @Jayce444's way. Dependencies would download one time atleast.

Comment: `create-react-app` is also installing dependencies. If you will to have old dependencies. You can do it once, store the folder some where and clone it whenever you want..

Comment: Everytime you do npm i, it also checks for updated packages and updates your package.json . The app can be made offline but your node modules will be downloaded ( they are added to git ignore) everytime you upload them to git.
If net is really an issue there then I'd suggest getting a pen drive or something where you can upload your files and access them without re-downloading

Comment: Oh true, it doesn't bundle the dependencies. So yeah, you'll pretty much just have to create a blank app then store it somewhere and use that (copy/paste) when starting a new app

Comment: Thanks everyone for your contribution. The most common suggestion has been to copy a local one and use it for subsequent needs. i've had one downloading for the past one hjour once it gets completed i'll copy it for future use. Thanks Everyone

Answer (score 6):

Now there is an [**NPM package**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app-offline) for that it called **create-react-app-offline**
Installation :

```sh
npm i - g create-react-app-offline
```

Usage :

```sh
crao -n <app-name>
```

For more informations on [GitHub](https://github.com/Baronsindo/create-react-app-offline)

Comment: In order for this to work in Windows the user folder must be added to the Path environment variable because the installation creates two files (crao and crao.cmd). It's located in "c:\users\username\"

Answer (score 1):

Every-time you do npm i, it also checks for updated packages and updates your package.json . The app can be made offline but your node modules will be downloaded ( they are added to git ignore) if you upload them to git.

If net is really an issue there then I'd suggest getting a **pen drive** or something where you can upload your files and access them without re-downloading

Comment: I can't upvote comments yet, but thanks for the suggestion i'll go with it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a npm package called create-react-app-offline which initializes the react project offline. And I checked it myself.
Here's the link

[Create React App Offline Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app-offline)

Just install it globally and run the crao -n <app_name>